# Linux terminal: how to add a newline without a carriage return?

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-interface, newline

In a Linux terminal, how can a newline (line feed?) be added without issuing a carriage return/issuing the command?

For example, in my case, I'd like to add several lines to a git commit comment, like so:

```
$ git commit -m "1. Removed comment blocks
  2. updated .gitignore
  3. added goto statement to hander
  --Miklas"
```

How do I add these line feeds for a multiple-line comment without actually entering the command?

I've googled around and tried a number of things (shift+return, alt+return, ctrl+return.. etc), but no luck. Tyvm Keith :^)

Comment: Don't provide the message "inline" at the command-line, and let `git commit` invoke the standard editor of yours (`$EDITOR`) so you can edit the message using any formatting you'd like.

Comment: Just type `git commit -m "message<enter><enter>More description"<enter>`

Comment: @KamilCuk when I press <enter> it submits the command!

Comment: Did you type `"` ? What shell are you using?

Comment: And remember that the first line is used as a *summary* of the commit. If you want to add more details do it as a separate paragraph.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't type it inline?

Comment: @KamilCuk Git bash, ssh'd into a Centos rig using ``/bin/bash``. I type ``"`` at the beginning and end of the comment block... how does that help with newlines?

Comment: `and end of the comment block` then don't. Type `"something<enter>` not `"something"<enter>`. If you leave `"` quotation open, the shell should show `> ` and let you type on the next line.

Comment: @KamilCuk oh crap that worked!!! ty add as a real answer and then I will check it. :D

Comment: You can also use `$'1.Removed comment blocks\n2. updated .gitignore\n3. added goto statement'`

Comment: what you've shown above should work just fine in any Bourne compliant shell.  My guess is that you are using a csh variant.  Best solution for this (and many other issues) is to stop using csh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells generally come with a support of multiline continuation of commands. If shell "detects" that the previous command is not "complete" and you typed enter, it will print `PS2` and let you continue inputting a command. Default `PS2="> "`.

```
# I type:
# git commit -m "message<enter><enter>description"<enter>
$ git commit -m "message
> 
> description"
no changes added to commit
```

It works also for with shell operators, like `for`, `while`, `if`, `case`:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3
> do
> echo $i
> done
1
2
3
```

I found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toRrlBJBByM&t=218) that shows the behavior.

You may also use C-ish quoting in bash:

```
git commit -m $'message\n\ndescription\n'
```

I sometimes use process subtitution with `printf`:

```
git commit -m "$(printf "%s\n" "message" "" "description")"
```

And finally you may type just:

```
git commit
```

that should open a full file editor, by default `vim`. In that editor type the multiline message you want, save and quit the editor and the file content will be taken as the commit message.